# Can't import functions from Python file in the same directory

Tags: python

I created two Python scripts and put them in the same directory:

*myfunctions.py*

```
def f(x):
  return x**2

def g(x):
  return x**3
```

*mytest.py*

```
from myfunctions import f, g

print f(2)
print g(3)
```

This isn't working, how do I get this to work?

It works when the files are in my home directory, but I don't know how to make it work when they're in some other directory.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @deathangel908 `No module named myfunctions`

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to have empty `__init__.py` file in the same directory to mark directory as a module

Comment: Are you sure you have correct names? try to rename `myfunctions.py` to `a.py` and check if it still produces `No module named a`. Becase the bare example above works.

Comment: just renamed it to `a.py` and still get the error `no module named a`, I'm using Python version 2.7.10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: so I just moved my files to my home directory and now it works, but how do I make it work when the files aren't in my home directory?

Comment: Try to remove `.pyc` files.

Comment: strange, I just made a new directory and put them in there and it works there too, so it must have something to do with the other directories or the files which are in them, possibly the .pyc files you're right.  But what if I need there to be .pyc files in the same directory, what do I do?

Comment: Usually `.pyc` files works ok. Something prevents python from refreshing those. Check if they have right permissions ( like if you ran python from `root` before and now from another user)

Comment: An `__init__.py` file shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: ok so it's not working in the folder I need it to work in, what are the permissions I should change?